# How to send F9-F12 to curses program running inside Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal.app

F9-F12 are used by Mac OS X, and I don't want to get rid of them, I just want to be able to send F9-F12 occasionally to programs inside terminal (mostly F9/F10).

Some programs like `mc` support sequence Escape 9 as synonym for F9 etc. but it's not universal.

It there any way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

fn-Cmd-F9 works as F9 in the Terminal.app on my MacBook Pro, running Mountain Lion 10.8.

Comment: On my MacBook Air running Mavericks, it's fn-Option-Fkey, not fn-Command-Fkey.

Comment: On MacBook Pro running Yosemite, fn-Cmd-F9 works; fn-Opt-F9 just inserts tilde. (I'm using it within emacs.)

Answer (score 5):

You can run an AppleScript (e.g. by wrapping it in a *Service* in Automator with the *Run AppleScript* action, with *no input* in *Terminal*) that executes the following:

```
tell application "System Events" 
    tell expose preferences to set the properties of the all windows shortcut to {function key:F1}
    key code 101 # press F9
    tell expose preferences to set the properties of the all windows shortcut to {function key:F9}
end tell
```

This will temporarily assign a different shortcut to what's bound to F9, press F9, and revert the setting. The setting names are the following for the other Expose preferences:

```
all windows shortcut
application windows shortcut
show desktop shortcut
dashboard shortcut
```

The key codes for F9 to F12 are the following:

```
F9 101
F10 109
F11 103
F12 111
```

You can assign keyboard shortcuts to services in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services* You will need to learn another shortcut (e.g. `Command-F9`), but at least you can press a key to initiate the action. For shortcuts using F-keys, see the last paragraph in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/236415/hide-all-applications-and-show-a-specific-app-with-shortcut-key/236438#236438).

---

You can alternatively configure a hotkey/macro application like [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) to press the escape sequence you get from `cat -v` when pressing one of the F-keys while you deactivated the shortcuts.

```
$ cat -v
^[[20~^[[21~^[[23~^[[24~
```

These are F9 to F12, in order.

In Butler, it looks like this for F9:

[image]

I pressed `Ctrl-[`, `[`, `2`, `0`, `~` for that sequence. On my keyboard layout, `~` is `Shift-backtick`, that's why the *Shift* modifier is visible. Works anyway.

Configure a shortcut and you can start pressing that to get the escape sequence:

[image]

Works in `mc`, and I don't recall another CLI program with F-keys at the moment. But it's not the `mc` specific escape sequence, so it will probably work in others.

---

Alternatively, many command line applications understand `Esc, 1` (sequence) to mean `F1`, through to `Esc, 0` meaning `F10`.

Comment: Ah, good morning Mrs Sledgehammer! Do allow me the pleasure of introducing you to Mr Nut...

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the keyboard shortcut for <kbd>F12</kbd> under:

keyboard preferences > keyboard shortcuts

Comment: This wasn't enough by itself for me, but is along the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add that if you are on a laptop, you're not actually using F9-F12, you're pressing "next song", "audio mute", "volume down" (example from recent macbookpro). To actually press F9-F12, keep 'Fn' pressed while using the same key.

On the desktop, if you have stuff like Exposé, Spaces, and so on mapped to the actual F9-F12 keyboard keys, I find it useful to associate those functions with additional mouse buttons (eg. I use the 'lateral button pair' of the Mighty Mouse to activate Exposé) or screen edges (eg. I have 'screen standby' in top-left) - but this is actually a subjective matter.

Comment: Turning this stuff off is the first thing I do on every new Mac. Expose etc. F9 is always F9, never next song.

Answer (score 0):

This is the two step process I used to get CoRD (Remote Desktop for Mac):

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"
2. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Uncheck "Show Desktop", "Show Dashboard"

The first step is what @taw is talking about in one of the comments; it gets function keys f1-f10 working. The second step stops f11 and f12 key presses from being intercepted by OSX.