# Hide all applications and show a specific app with shortcut key

Tags: macos, shortcuts

OSX 10.6.  I got rid of dashboard shortcut, never used it.  I use stickies a lot on my desktop. Can be a pain getting to it at times.  Any idea how to map the F4 key to: hide all applications and only show stickies?

Answer (score 3):

Press `Cmd-Opt-H` to hide all other applications.

---

You can use Automator to create a *Service* that activates Stickies and hides all other applications. Start Automator, create a *Service* that receives *no input* in *any application* and add the *Run AppleScript* action with the following code:

```
tell application "Stickies" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "h" using {command down, option down}
```

Save as "Show Only Stickies" and it will show up in any application's *Application Menu » Services*.

You might need to enable support for assistive devices in *System Preferences » Universal Access* for this to work.

---

Assign a keyboard shortcut to your Service in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.

If this doesn't work (e.g. F4 doesn't work in that list), go to *Application Shortcuts*, add a new one for the menu item "Show Only Stickies", press F4 for the shortcut, and confirm. You need to switch applications for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another Applescript:

```
tell app "System Events" to set visible of processes to false
activate app "Stickies"
```

You could also save separate scripts for hiding all applications, and opening for example Stickies.