# Terminal app on Mac OS X - normal keys

Tags: macos, terminal

There are some default terminal things different for the Mac (for example, Command C to copy and Command V to paste rather than simply highlighting/right clicking).

These are fine with me. What bothers me though is I can't figure out how to click or use the F keys.

The main app I have problems with is htop. Htop supports clicking on column names to sort, etc. Also, to exit the app, you are supposed to press F10. But F10 simply mutes my volume. I've tried different combinations of things like alt F10.

I usually have to quit htop by pressing CTRL-C

Any ideas on how to get normal terminal behaviors? Normal meaning linux

Comment: Supa in swedish means Boozing. ie; Boozing user!

Comment: Anything new with this issue?

Comment: you can quit htop by pressing the 'q' key. Other simple (non-function-key) commands are listed by pressing the 'h' key.

Answer (score 5):

You have two issues here:

- On your Mac, like on most laptops, the function key row is used for both regular F keys and special hardware or system functionality. One of these is invoked while you hold down `Fn`, the other while you don't. Open *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard* and change *Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys*.

**This is the issue you're currently facing: Pressing F10 doesn't actually press F10**

[image]

But even if you change the above preference, chances are some F keys are already used for other functions:

- Even when you've done that, OS X might use F keys for system-wide keyboard shortcuts. In the same preference pane, change over to *Keyboard Shortcuts*, and check the *Dashboard & Dock* and *Exposé & Spaces* categories. Disable or change any F key shortcuts. Alternatively, you can open the *Exposé & Spaces* preference pane in *System Preferences* to change the shortcuts there (with more options).

[image]

---

Also, you should take a look at [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/questions/182456/how-to-send-f9-f12-to-curses-program-running-inside-terminal-app/237970#237970) in a related topic. You might like having Exposé and Dashboard bound to those function keys, after all.

---

To use some F keys without pressing Fn, while using others with pressing Fn (and using their special functions without Fn), use [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/).

Answer (score 1):

To have F-keys available you'd have to disable the system wide shortcuts assigned to them.  You can do that in **System Preferences**.

[image]

To be able to use a mouse I think you'd have to use some other terminal application.  For example [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) supports a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a linux user and never use F10 to exit for an application. I also use the standard terminal on Mac and for exit any terminal app i use `q`. It works with 'top' in my Mac and with htop at last in my linux box.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but this works for me (in Yosemite) without using any 3rd party apps or changing configuration.

While in terminal to use `Fx` keys you can simply press `fn + CMD + Fx`. For example to get F10 you would `fn + CMD + F10`.

Welcome