# Something is hijacking my F8 key in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

I have iMac 21.5", and it came with Snow Leopard installed by default. That's fine, but I was eligible for free Lion update, which I did.

Now I can't get my <kbd>F8</kbd> key to work as a ... well, <kbd>F8</kbd> key. It's constantly bound to showing Mission Control screen. I have checked in System preferences and there is no key binding to this action.

It drives me crazy already, because I need this key for deleting files in Midnight Commander through SSH connection.

Comment: How about simply rebinding the key within Midnight Commander?

Comment: Have you checked *System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts* If you find something there? It might not be configurable in Mission Control preference pane

Comment: @DanielBeck: I have checked Keyboard Shortcuts. There's default, i.e. Ctrl+Up. But it really doesn't matter what I set it there. It could be F15 as well as disabled. Pressing F8 always shows Mission Control.

Comment: As a workaround, you can do what I suggest [here](http://superuser.com/questions/182456/how-to-send-f9-f12-to-curses-program-running-inside-terminal-app/237970#237970) and press `Esc` followed by `8`.

Comment: To be sure, your System Preferences settings look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7l6qf.png) and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XHTU7.png)? Have you tried toggling the relevant settings to make OS X write them to disk again in case the configuration got messed up?

Comment: These are my settings: [Mission Control](http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/6879/zrzutekranu2011103o1125.png) and [Keyboard Shortcuts](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/6879/zrzutekranu2011103o1125.png). I have changed them several times. At all times work: the one I set AND F8 ;(